# Stats bug (again)?

Tags: support, statistics

Are we really this inactive, or are the stats broken (again)? On other sites, the stats seem to work fine...

[image: 0 Visitors...]

0 visitors per Day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume it only counts from the start of public, which was half an hour ago, and because of caching it hasn't updated yet.

Comment: Sidenote: The answer is always caching.

Comment: Yup, works again now.